# im getting this error in sql server 2008 : Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

hey im trying to use this code but i dont know why im getting this error :

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure stat_mob_user_spec, Line 23
Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.
```

Code is :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stat_mob_user_spec] (@bt NVARCHAR(60) = NULL)
AS
    DECLARE @ResultValue FLOAT,
            @test        NVARCHAR(70)

    BEGIN TRAN

    SET @test = 'and blood_type = ' + @bt;

    IF @bt = 'abc'
      BEGIN
          SET @test = '';
      END

    SELECT @ResultValue = COUNT(id_tips)
    FROM   tips,
           blood
    WHERE  blood_id = id_blood + @test;

    IF @ResultValue <> 0
      BEGIN
          ROLLBACK TRAN
      END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
          COMMIT TRAN
      END

    RETURN @ResultValue
```

this code is working if i put in the parameter ( abc ) ... ill got result .. but im getting error if i try anything else ... any help ?

Im using sql server 2008

Comment: You are trying to concatenate a string `@test` to your `where` clause.  You need to look at using dynamic sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is:

```
SELECT @ResultValue = COUNT(id_tips)
from tips,blood 
where blood_id = id_blood + @test ;
```

You are adding a string value (`@test`) to whatever `id_blood` is.  I imagine that it is a `bigint` and this is not allowed.

It looks like you might be thinking dynamic SQL.  But this is not how you code dynamic SQL.  I would suggest that you talk to someone locally about the correct way to write stored procedures in SQL Server (or at least read the documentation on the `select` statement).  Also, learn proper join syntax.  Just say "no" to commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: thatss the word .. "dynamic sql ".. thx man ! :D  im gonna make some research about it now ! btw im new in sql :P

Comment: If you want a good example step by step of how to write Dynamic SQL I just answered the question yesterday... though its a different scenario look at my accepted answer for a step by step way of how to write it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360118/sql-variables-as-column-names-in-where-clause/18363855#18363855